# Scribe documentation generation fails under Laravel-Vapor

Tags: scribe, laravel-vapor

I am runnig "php artisan scribe:generate" using vapor laravel commands, and get the job ends with errors, despite the fact that on my developement system (Laravel 10 on Windows 11) the same command runs without errors.

This is the output for *php artisan scribe:generate* in vapor command window:

> Processing route: [GET] api/info
> Processed route: [GET] api/info
> Processing route: [POST] api/auth/login
> Processed route: [POST] api/auth/login
> Processing route: [POST] api/auth/hash
> Processed route: [POST] api/auth/hash
> Processing route: [POST] api/auth/logout
> Processed route: [POST] api/auth/logout
> Processing route: [GET] api/auth/role
> Processed route: [GET] api/auth/role
> Processing route: [GET] api/auth/permission
> Processed route: [GET] api/auth/permission
> Processing route: [GET] api/project
> Processed route: [GET] api/project
> Processing route: [GET] api/esolver/project/{project}
> Processed route: [GET] api/esolver/project/{project}
> Processing route: [GET] api/esolver/update/{project}
> Processed route: [GET] api/esolver/update/{project}
> Processing route: [GET] api/esolver/sync/{project}
> Processed route: [GET] api/esolver/sync/{project}
> Processing route: [POST] api/in_hook/new
> Processed route: [POST] api/in_hook/new
> Processing route: [POST] api/in_hook/start
> Processed route: [POST] api/in_hook/start
> Processing route: [POST] api/in_hook/stop
> Processed route: [POST] api/in_hook/stop
> Processing route: [POST] api/in_hook/delete
> Processed route: [POST] api/in_hook/delete
> Processing route: [POST] api/recipients/upload
> Processed route: [POST] api/recipients/upload
> Processing route: [POST] api/recipients/normalize
> Processed route: [POST] api/recipients/normalize
> Processing route: [POST] api/recipients/deduplicate
> Processed route: [POST] api/recipients/deduplicate
> Processing route: [GET] api/maps/show/{mapid?}
> Processed route: [GET] api/maps/show/{mapid?}
> Processing route: [POST] api/maps/set
> Processed route: [POST] api/maps/set
> Processing route: [PUT] api/maps/update
> Processed route: [PUT] api/maps/update
> Processing route: [DELETE] api/maps/remove/{mapid}
> Processed route: [DELETE] api/maps/remove/{mapid}
> Processing route: [POST] api/external/address
> Processed route: [POST] api/external/address
>
> League\Flysystem\UnableToDeleteFile
>
> Unable to delete file located at: /var/task/.scribe/endpoints/00.yaml.
>
> at vendor/league/flysystem/src/UnableToDeleteFile.php:24
> 20▕     private $reason;
> 21▕
> 22▕     public static function atLocation(string $location, string $reason = '', Throwable $previous = null): UnableToDeleteFile
> 23▕     {
> 24▕         $e = new static(rtrim("Unable to delete file located at: {$location}. {$reason}"), 0, $previous);
> 25▕         $e->location = $location;
> 26▕         $e->reason = $reason;
> 27▕
> 28▕         return $e;
>
> 1   vendor/league/flysystem-local/LocalFilesystemAdapter.php:143
> League\Flysystem\UnableToDeleteFile::atLocation("/var/task/.scribe/endpoints/00.yaml", "")
>
> 2   vendor/league/flysystem/src/Filesystem.php:85
> League\Flysystem\Local\LocalFilesystemAdapter::delete(".scribe/endpoints/00.yaml")
>
> 3   vendor/knuckleswtf/scribe/src/Tools/Utils.php:212
> League\Flysystem\Filesystem::delete(".scribe/endpoints/00.yaml")
>
> 4   vendor/knuckleswtf/scribe/src/GroupedEndpoints/GroupedEndpointsFromApp.php:191
> Knuckles\Scribe\Tools\Utils::deleteFilesMatching(".scribe/endpoints", Object(Closure))
>
> 5   vendor/knuckleswtf/scribe/src/GroupedEndpoints/GroupedEndpointsFromApp.php:84
> Knuckles\Scribe\GroupedEndpoints\GroupedEndpointsFromApp::writeEndpointsToDisk([])
>
> 6   vendor/knuckleswtf/scribe/src/GroupedEndpoints/GroupedEndpointsFromApp.php:49
> Knuckles\Scribe\GroupedEndpoints\GroupedEndpointsFromApp::extractEndpointsInfoAndWriteToDisk(Object(Knuckles\Scribe\Matching\RouteMatcher))
>
> 7   vendor/knuckleswtf/scribe/src/Commands/GenerateDocumentation.php:51
> Knuckles\Scribe\GroupedEndpoints\GroupedEndpointsFromApp::get()
>
> 8   vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:36
> Knuckles\Scribe\Commands\GenerateDocumentation::handle(Object(Knuckles\Scribe\Matching\RouteMatcher), Object(Knuckles\Scribe\GroupedEndpoints\GroupedEndpointsFactory))
>
> 9   vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php:41
> Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container{closure}()
>
> 10  vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:93
> Illuminate\Container\Util::unwrapIfClosure(Object(Closure))
>
> 11  vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:35
> Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Object(Closure))
>
> 12  vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:662
> Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), [])
>
> 13  vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:208
> Illuminate\Container\Container::call()
>
> 14  vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:326
> Illuminate\Console\Command::execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
>
> 15  vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:177
> Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command::run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
>
> 16  vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:1081
> Illuminate\Console\Command::run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
>
> 17  vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:320
> Symfony\Component\Console\Application::doRunCommand(Object(Knuckles\Scribe\Commands\GenerateDocumentation), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
>
> 18  vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:174
> Symfony\Component\Console\Application::doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
>
> 19  vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php:201
> Symfony\Component\Console\Application::run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
>
> 20  artisan:41
> Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))

Is there any one that experienced the same ?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this same problem. Unfortunately Scribe works with the local file system and this does not work in the Lambda instance.
I've created an issue for this: https://github.com/knuckleswtf/scribe/issues/768

For now we are generating the docs locally and not in the CICD....

---

When deploying to vapor the error below occurs.
I've tried Attaching Storage https://docs.vapor.build/resources/storage.html#attaching-storage
And temporary storage https://docs.vapor.build/resources/storage.html#temporary-storage

This is the code where it is failing. Because (as I see it) it will always select a local filesystem, where vapor does not have/support one:
https://github.com/knuckleswtf/scribe/blob/a720537cb6c03e8900d3ef800bdf3f27599e856e/src/Tools/Utils.php#L194

Exception:

```
Unable to delete file located at: /var/task/.scribe/endpoints/00.yaml.

  at vendor/league/flysystem/src/UnableToDeleteFile.php:24
     20▕     private $reason;
     21▕ 
     22▕     public static function atLocation(string $location, string $reason = '', Throwable $previous = null): UnableToDeleteFile
     23▕     {
  ➜  24▕         $e = new static(rtrim("Unable to delete file located at: {$location}. {$reason}"), 0, $previous);
     25▕         $e->location = $location;
     26▕         $e->reason = $reason;
     27▕ 
     28▕         return $e;

      +19 vendor frames 

  20  artisan:41
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```